# System.ArgumentException when reading a file into a byte array

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

To upload a file using a `ByteArrayContent` for `HttpClient`i'm reading a `StorageFile` into  a `byte` array. The code is working without problems with images, but its not working for files im generating through a `AudioVideoCaptureDevice`- even through the files are NOT empty which i double checked. **It'll accessing the file in any way*:

```
byte[] data;
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

try {
    Debug.WriteLine("uploading: "+ fileName);
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("data\\"+LocalPayload);
    var probs = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine("path " + file.Path + "" + " size " + probs.Size);

    try
    {

        var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
        using (var dataReader = new DataReader(stream))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("stream size is " + stream.Size);
            data = new byte[stream.Size];
            await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
            dataReader.ReadBytes(data);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("stream was read");
        content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("file not found", e.ToString());
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("could not create byte array for file: " + e.ToString());
        return;
    }

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("could not read file: " + e.ToString());
    return;
}
```

This is the exception

```
could not read file: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TestApp.Models.Item.<Upload>d__1f.MoveNext()
```

To Capture the file i'm first using to record sound

```
IStorageFolder applicationFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var dataFolder = await applicationFolder.CreateFolderAsync("data", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
outputFile = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(audioFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
stream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
await dev.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(stream);
```

and after some user interaction i'm calling

```
await dev.StopRecordingAsync();
Debug.WriteLine("stopped recording");
await stream.FlushAsync();
stream.Dispose();
```

Any suggestions why some files are working and some are not?

Thanks!

**UPDATE** added code for creating the file and the source of the folder

**UPDATE2** added code for surrounding try catch to read file size

Comment: is the file definitely closed? What's the size of stream.Size in this case?

Comment: It seems to be linked to the use of the await methods and the compiler generated code. Try feeding it files with incrementally larger sizes to see if it cuts off after a certain size. Do you have any line numbers? might help make things a bit clearer as so far the message appears to be mostly compiler generated functions. Try catching the exception and printing all its details.

Comment: How do you get `folder`?

Comment: @oren the Debug.WriteLine in the using block is never called

Comment: @den, i added the folder-line

Comment: @pharap i tested around and it seems that it'll crash always when accessing the file, not only with the stream->byte[] code. I cannot read the file properties through `GetBasicPropertiesAsync`. So i guess its something about how i store the file and close the stream? I added some code to show how i do it. The stream should be closed because even after the app is crashed and i try to acces the file again, its not working. (i guess at least after a restart the file should be closed?)

Comment: another update: when i iterate through the folder from a test-button on a page, the GetBasicPropertiesAsync works like a charm: https://gist.github.com/magegu/8dffb40502310e84fcea to it seems to be the access from another thread maybe?

Comment: Have you considered using a more event driven technique as opposed to awaiting all the async processes? Also, is Spacedeck.Models.Artifact one of the classes you use in your program? I can't find in in the msdn archives, which implies it's from a 3rd party library or a class you've made, in which case the solution might be there. I'm pretty sure it's linked to a foreach loop since <Upload>d__1f.MoveNext() is the kind of signature generated by the whole foreach enumeration loop. (I was reading a dll file in NP++, don't ask, I was curious)

Comment: @pharap, i already solved the isse with my answer below (i could not mark it as correkt yet) thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: No Problem. I didn't realise the answer had been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was due to a wrong file name for the sound file. I saved absolute path and not only the file name as used in the code above.

Thanks everyone who tried to help!